# script which creates a filename in certain pattern and deletes any previously created files in the same pattern if any?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to write a script that creates a file that stores the hostname and date in YEARMONTHDAYHOURMINSEC  and prints all the enviroment variables in the system and delete all the previously created files in the directory if any or else create a new file.

So the script should search through the directory and delete the previous file in that pattern but should not delete other files.

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
echo $(hostname) >>env.$time.txt
echo date:$time >>env.$time.txt
echo $(env)>>env.$time.txt
cat env.$time.txt
```

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots.

Comment: Just put `rm env.*.txt` at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix to your existing script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set location of backup such as `/var/log`
envDir=/path/to/dir

mkdir -p $envDir/junk

mv $envDir/env.*.txt $envDir/junk 2> /dev/null

time=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
echo $(hostname) >> $envDir/env.$time.txt
echo date:$time >> $envDir/env.$time.txt
echo $(env)>>$envDir/env.$time.txt
cat $envDir/env.$time.txt

rm $envDir/junk/*
```

Note that some things can be improved such as your `echo $(env)` which will produce practically unusable data.  You should instead just do it as `env` which will be line delimited, and easily importable.

The filename can also be defined earlier to simplify your code such as setting and make it more maintainable.

Here is a the slightly improved version with a additional comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set location of backup such as `/var/log`
# !!! Update this!
envDir=/path/to/dir

# set backup time
time=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

# set full file name for the backup
envFile=$envDir/env.$time.txt

# make temporary directory and ignore if it already exists
mkdir -p $envDir/junk

# move existing environment backup files to junk until we have our new output
mv $envDir/env.*.txt $envDir/junk 2> /dev/null

hostname >> $envFile
echo date:$time >> $envFile
env >> $envFile
cat $envFile

# remove the backup(s)
rm $envDir/junk/*
```

Comment: `mkdir -p` gets rid of the need for `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: @Kusalananda:  Good point, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this script and it works. This script creates a new file and deletes the old file, if one exists, in your user home directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATETIME=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
rm ~/env.*.txt
echo "$(hostname)
date:$DATETIME
$(env)" | tee ~/env.$DATETIME.txt
```

*First*,  changed `date` to `DATETIME` because `date` seemed more likely to already be defined.

*Next,*  `rm ~/env.*.txt` deletes any file in the user $HOME directory or ~/ using a glob as a wildcard so to only match the static or fixed portion of the filename.

If any output file created using the script should mstch this and should be deleted from the home directory.

If a file does not exist, the user should receive an output error message in the terminal that the file does not exist. This message can be ignored and should not exist any sunsequent time the script is run.

Also, I used `tee` instead of `>>` just out of habbit as tee doesn't usually have any problems ever.

Finally `echo` does not need to be used more than one time here. I used an open ended double-quotation mark on the first line, included the next two lines to be written to the file, and ended with a closed double-quotation mark on the last line then piped to `tee` to write the output to file.

When `tee` is used, the contents written to the file will print in the terminal so `cat` seemed redundant.

Additionally, you can append an output to a file as a new line at the end of any exsisting file by using the `-a` flag with `tee` like this: `tee -a`

Comment: Your solution looks good, but it would be better if you explained how it works.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I made some changes to explain some stuff.